# Sending data from FPGA to Raspberry Pi using SPI protocol

Tags: python, vhdl, spi

I have an FPGA and I want to capture working values (usually 4 bytes in size) within the FPGA using a Raspberry pi and SPI protocol where the slave is the FPGA. The Rpi outputs the ar_clk and ar_en(enable). The FPGA outputs ar_dat(data). The problem I have is that I sometimes miss read a bit. My VHDL code below should do the following: When the enable pin(ar_en) goes to zero or ar_clk pin transitions to low, the FPGA waits about 1024 counts and puts a data bit on the ar_dat pin. It then has time to relax before the rising edge of the ar_clk where it gets read by the Rpi.
Below the VHDL code is my Python Code. The python code should read ar_dat on the rising edge of ar_clk.
My cable length between the two is about 1m. The signals look clean from an o-scope. I am using Red, blue, and Orange wire from an RJ45 cable with all other 5 ends tied to ground at the Rpi (pin6) and tied together to ground on a custom wired RJ45 connector with the 5 ends to ground on my FPGA board. I have a Deo Nano Soc board plugged into a PCB board.
Please help me find where/why I am miss reading bits.

```
 screen_shot : process(CLK)
      begin
            if rising_edge(CLK) then
                if ar_en = '1' then  -- (purple cable orange wire[24]) -- Initializes these 5 when high
                        ss_timer <= (others => '0'); -- 32 bit SLV
                        ss_value <= (others => '0'); -- 32 bit SLV 
                        ss_cntr  <= 1; -- 0 to 1023 integer
                        ss_word  <= 0; -- 0 to 1023 integer
                        ar_dat <= '0'; -- data bit to Raspberry Pi
                end if;
                            
            if ar_en = '0' then -- (purple cable orange wire[24]) The SDI data enable bit
                ss_timer <= ss_timer + 1; -- 
                
                if ar_clk = '1' then --  10240 Hz from Raspberry Pi
                    ss_timer <= (others => '0');
                end if;
                
                if ar_clk = '0' then-- (purple cable green wire[23])
                    
                    if ss_timer = 1024 then  -- This is an abitrary time to make sure value is set and settled
                        ar_dat <= ss_value(31- ss_word);  -- Put bit before rising edge (purple cable blue wire[21])
                    end if;
                
                    if ss_timer = 1024 + 5 then
                        ss_word <= ss_word + 1;
                    end if;
                    
                    if ss_word = 32 and ss_timer = 1024 + 10 then
                        ss_cntr <= ss_cntr + 1;
                    end if;
                                
                    if ss_word = 32 and ss_timer = 1024 + 15 then
                        ss_word <= 0;
                    end if;
                end if; -- if ar_clk = '0'
                            
                case ss_cntr is
                    when 1 =>  ss_value <= "10101010101010101010101010101010";
                    when 2 =>  ss_value <= "10101010101010101010101010101010";
                    when 3 =>  ss_value <= "10101010101010101010101010101010";
                    when 4 =>  ss_value <= "10101010101010101010101010101010";
                    when 5 =>  ss_value <= "10101010101010101010101010101010";
                    when others => ss_value <= "11111110101010101010101010101010";
                end case;               
        
            end if; -- if ar_en = '0'
            
        end if; -- Rising Edge
        
  end process;
```

Python Code:

```
import spidev
import time
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
print("start")
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.mode = 0b00
spi.max_speed_hz =10240
#print(val)
for j in range(0, 2):
    val = spi.readbytes(20)
    print(val)
spi.close()
```

Comment: Do you see the missing bit on the oscilloscope? Do you take all timing into account? The RasPi might read the data line before the FPGA put the value on it.

Comment: Today, I am currently using Signal Tap (a virtual o-scope) and I see the missing bits there. It must be in my VHDL code. Trying to find it now.

Comment: Did you simulate it?

Comment: Yes, I did a simulation and it worked when I simulated data input. I also recorded data with a Saleae pro 8 and Signal Tap at the same time in real time. I see the clock arriving at regular intervals and I see the same wrong data on both. The wrong data appears to be random. I see no bounce using Saleae. In VHDL, I changed all counters in this process to integer format. I am thinking of scrapping this VHDL process and rewriting it but I want to find my VHDL error.

Comment: "all counters" I meant ss_timer...

Comment: Thank you all. I found an issue. A problem was the ss_word counter. I will rewrite this process with a slightly different style that should help me make it error free.